# Criar Objeto ProfileCommon em Asp.Net Membership

Tags: webforms, asp.net-membership

Preciso criar um "objeto de perfil" em Asp.net Membership (Controle de segurança do asp.net).

Meu `Web.config`:

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="labPuc" />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="UserId" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Nome" type="System.String" />
    <add name="Email" type="System.String" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Como faria para gerar esse perfil?

```
ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(usuario);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes é importante dizer que `Profile` e `Membership` são duas coisas completamente diferentes, tanto que `Profile` tem sua própria biblioteca ([System.Web.Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.profile(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Esse objeto `Profile` é dinâmico, então você definiu ele da maneira que desejou no seu arquivo `Web.config` contendo:

- `UserId`
- `Nome`
- `Email`

É importante dizer que **este objeto deve ser inteiramente montado pela sua aplicação, principalmente quanto aos atributos definidos no seu `Web.config`**.

Para o usuário logado, esse objeto criado dinamicamente está acessível através da propriedade `HttpContext.Current.Profile`.

`ProfileCommon` não existe implementada pra projetos a partir do Framework .NET 4.0. A Microsoft na época [colocou isso discretamente num manual de migração deles (veja o tópico "Converting Profile Object Code")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx). Você pode implementar a sua própria classe `ProfileCommon`, se quiser, que vai funcionar como um envelope para a classe `ProfileBase`, mais ou menos assim:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;

namespace MeuProjeto.Infrastructure
{
    public class ProfileCommon : ProfileBase
    {

        public ProfileUserData UserData
        { 
            get { return (ProfileUserData) GetPropertyValue("UserData"); }       
        } 

        public static ProfileCommon GetProfile() 
        { 
            return (ProfileCommon) HttpContext.Current.Profile; 
        } 

        public static ProfileCommon GetProfile(string userName) 
        { 
            return (ProfileCommon) Create(userName); 
        }  
    }

    // Aqui coloquei mais umas coisas, como um exemplo de como posso
    // estender esse objeto com coisas mais complexas, mas não que seja 
    // realmente necessário pra resposta.
    [Serializable]
    public class ProfileUserData
    {
        public string Endereco { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Repare que usando assim:

```
ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(usuario);
```

`ProfileCommon` virá vazio, porque o método `Create` de `ProfileBase` criará o objeto dinamicamente com o básico do básico, [o que pode ser visto aqui](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Profile/HttpProfileBase.cs).

Portanto, pra preencher seu objeto corretamente, você ainda teria que alterar seu envelope pra trazer o restante das informações:

```
public static ProfileCommon GetProfile(string userName) 
{ 
    var profileCommon = (ProfileCommon) Create(userName);
    profileCommon.UserID = //Coloque aqui o UserId
    profileCommon.Nome = // Coloque aqui o nome
    profileCommon.Email = // Coloque aqui o e-mail
    return profileCommon;
}
```

Comment: public static ProfileCommon GetProfile(string userName) 
{ } Como faço para recuperar os dados do banco?

Comment: @Marconi Como sua aplicação faz pra trabalhar com o banco? Isso é você que tem que saber.

Comment: Fiz o login com a autenticação do Memberships. Tentei recuperar o meu profile e nada através HttpContext.Current.Profile

Comment: Obviamente, porque o objeto está vazio. É você que monta ele.

Comment: ProfileCommon então se eu conseguir atribuir valores ao aobjeto ProfileCommon eu conseguirei pegar o valor dele em qualquer página?

Comment: Entedi a sua lógica cigano. Quando eu Solicitar esse perfil pelo GetProfile devo fazer uma requisição ao asp_Membership e atribuir os valores ao profileCommon? Isso fará com que meu perfil esteja acessivel a todas as páginas?

Comment: @Marconi Exatamente. A lógica não é minha hehehehe. O componente funciona assim.