# Persistir dados no ProfileCommon

Tags: webforms, asp.net-profile

Criei um web site. asp.net C#

Adicionei no meu web config dessa forma

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="principal.aspx"
  name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>

<roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="true"
  cookieName=".ASPROLES"
  cookieTimeout="30"
  cookiePath="/"
  cookieRequireSSL="false"
  cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
  cookieProtection="All" >
  <providers>
    <add
      name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
      connectionStringName="labPuc"
      applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="labPuc" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="2" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="labPuc"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="UserId" type="System.String"/>
    <add name="Email" type="System.String"/>
    <add name="TipoPermissao" type="System.String"/>
    <add name="Habilitado" type="System.String"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Quando vou criar um usuário crio também o meu perfil dessa forma:

```
//Provedor de perfil
ProfileCommon perfil = (ProfileCommon)ProfileCommon.Create(login.Text, true);
perfil.UserId = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
perfil.Email = user.Email;
perfil.Habilitado = "S";
perfil.TipoPermissao = "Administrador";
perfil.Save();
```

Até aí tudo bem. Quando vou logar pego o ProfileCommon assim:

```
ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(Login.Text);
```

Quando sou redirecionado para outra página, tento pegar uma propriedade do meu perfil dessa forma. `Profile.TipoPermissao` porem o Profile vem vazio, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que recriar o objeto de perfil toda vez que carrega informações do seu usuário. Portanto, aqui:

```
ProfileCommon profile = Profile.GetProfile(Login.Text);
```

No `GetProfile` você tem que montar o objeto de novo. [Como te respondi aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33250/criar-objeto-profilecommon-em-asp-net-membership), o método `GetProfile` precisa montar esse objeto.

Comment: Cigano lá na empresa uma vez logado, você não precisa carregar os dados novamente você tem acesso aos atributos do perfil com o Profile.Atributo. não precisando caregar o perfil novamente toda vez que acesso uma página diferente.

Comment: @Marconi Como assim? O Profile não necessariamente depende da sessão.

Comment: Essa variável `profileCommon` expira toda vez que você muda de página, por isso que ela não pode ser confiada pra persistir informações. É uma variável somente leitura das informações do seu usuário.

Comment: Acho estranho porque o lá da empresa os dados continuam no perfil, deve ter alguma Hbilitação dentro do web.conf.

Comment: Desvendei o segredo @Cigano, o profile é integrado junto ao mesmberships, que por sua vez cria ticket(cookie) pra persistir as informações. Vou melhorar essa pergunta no fim de semana pra mim de melhor entendimento e ajudar a mais pessoas.