# Informações extras no login de um usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Meu cenário é o seguinte:

O usuário vai logar no sistema. Então vai ser exibido uma lista de itens e ele vai escolher um.

Preciso então que o sistema armazene o usuário logado e o item que ele escolheu.

Não sei como posso estar fazendo isso e desconheço as tecnologias que posso estar utilizando.

Atualmente para autenticação de meus projetos utilizo [FormsAuthentication](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22004/permiss%C3%B5es-de-usu%C3%A1rios), porém o mesmo não consigo armazenar mais de um valor (pelo menos eu não sei).

Achei a seguinte alternativa:

```
Forms.SetAuthCookie (UserName + "|" + UserId, true);

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    userId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('|')[1]);
}
```

Pensei também na utilização de `Session`, mas acho que existe uma tecnologia mais apropriada.

Comment: Penso que deves rever a tua questão... Não parece ter qualquer tipo de esforço de pesquisa

Comment: @CesarMiguel, editei minha pergunta, porém não sei mais o que colocar.

Comment: Por quanto tempo você precisa armazenar essa informação? Por alguns minutos? Meses? Pra sempre? Esse armazenamento é só para conveniência do usuário voltar ao site e rever as coisas como as selecionou da última vez, ou você vai fazer alguma análise ou processamento do seu lado?

Comment: @Renan, por um tempo curto... O tempo que dura o FormsAuthentication....

Comment: Isso meio que não fez sentido. Acho que se você disser o que vai fazer com essas informações fica mais fácil. Mas vou arriscar uma resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se tudo que você quer é ter esses valores para usar enquanto o usuário estiver logado - ou se quiser usar esses valores apenas na próxima requisição - você pode usar a sessão do usuário.

A sessão é um objeto que é único por usuário. Ela é criada quando o usuário autentica, e destruída quando ele é desconectado. Assim ela sobrevive, por exemplo, de uma requisição para outra. Ela fica no servidor, então pode continuar viva mesmo que o usuário mude de máquina ou ponto de acesso.

Um exemplo de uso comum de sessões é pra guardar "carrinhos de supermercado" dos usuários.

Para jogar valores na sessão:

```
Session[nomeDaVariavel] = foo;
```

Onde `nomeDaVariavel` é uma string arbitrária, e `foo` é um valor que você quer guardar apenas enquanto o usuário está logado.

Pra ler os valores, supondo que sejam strings:

```
string valor = (string)Session[nomeDaVariavel];
```

Se o valor não tiver sido armazenado, virá nulo.

Isso deve ser tudo que você precisa. Boa sorte, e se isso ajudou, não esqueça de fazer uma leitura aprofundada da [documentação oficial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx), que também sugere outras alternativas ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Pensei também na utilização de Session, mas acho que existe uma tecnologia mais apropriada.

Existe. É a tecnologia de [Profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Use uma implementação sua de [`ProfileBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase(v=vs.110).aspx) para guardar as opções de cada usuário.

Use [`ProfileManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) para gerenciar os perfis dos seus usuários.

Respondi recentemente algumas perguntas sobre isso que podem ser do seu interesse:

- [Criar Objeto ProfileCommon em Asp.Net Membership](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33250/criar-objeto-profilecommon-em-asp-net-membership/33269#33269)
- [Persistir dados no ProfileCommon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34097/persistir-dados-no-profilecommon)