# SESSÃO: Sistema confunde usuários que o acessam simultaneamente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quando 2 usuários acessam ao mesmo tempo o sistema, de alguma forma ele confunde os usuários, não somente o nome, mas sim suas permissões também...

Estou atribuindo a sessão após o login na ActionFilter

```
public class UsuarioAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    int idUsuario= new UsuarioNegocio().GetIdByExternalId(decodedToken.ExternalUserId.ToInt32());//Id vem de um token

    Usuario usuario = new UsuarioNegocio().GetById(idUsuario);

    filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Usuario"] = usuario;
}
```

E na BaseController tenho o seguinte método para recuperar a sessão:

```
public Usuario GetCurrentUser()
{
   return (Usuario)HttpContext.Session["Usuario"];
}
```

Alguém já teve este problema com sessão?

Comment: Talvez seja porque esteja usando uma variável estática. Assim quando outro usuário fazer login ela é atualizada, a não ser que você salve o objeto. Tenta uma Global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta é a maneira errada de persistir dados de usuário em sessão no ASP.NET MVC.

As alternativas a isto são:

- [Usar um objeto derivado de `ProfileBase` (explico aqui)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33250/criar-objeto-profilecommon-em-asp-net-membership/33269#33269);
- Usar um provedor de autenticação como o [ASP.NET Identity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+identity). [Exemplos aqui](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-identity).

---

**EDIT**

Você disse por resposta que está usando `OutputCache`, que é um recurso global. Ou seja, o primeiro usuário que criar a *cache* criará a informação de Session para todos.

```
[HttpGet, OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)]
```

Parece absurdo, mas faz todo o sentido, justamente porque os dados da sessão também são mantidos pelo `OutputCache`.

Answer (score 0):

O problema se encontrava na controller no método sair, estava assim:

```
[HttpGet, OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)]
```

Deixei apenas com o get e resolveu (não sei explicar o motivo):

```
[HttpGet]
```

Comment: Porque o `OutputCache` é global. Não é por usuário.

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano, se quiser dar como resposta copiando o que eu escrevi te deixo como melhor resposta!

Comment: Ok, atualizei a resposta com mais alguns comentários. Obrigado.